# R paste function repeats first argument for each word

Tags: r

Below is a code snippet written for writing the messages. But im not getting why the output prints the way below. Expected output is also given. I first thought the txt is a list type. But it is a character variable

```
writetext<-function(...){
   arguments <- list(...)
 if (length(arguments)>0){
   txt<- paste(arguments)
   if (length(txt)==0) return()
   strtime <- format(Sys.time(),"%I:%M:%S%p")
   txt <- paste(strtime,txt)
   message(txt)
```

}
}

```
writetext("abc","efg")  
01:05:13PM abc01:05:13PM efg

Expected :
01:05:13PM abcefg
```

Comment: From the help page on `paste`: `If the arguments are vectors, they are concatenated term-by-term to give a character  vector result`. This is why you're getting what looks like multiple outputs; it's `paste`'s default behavior (without specifying `collapse` as in the answer given by Jozef),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `paste0(txt, collapse = "")` :

```
writetext <- function(...) {
  arguments <- list(...)
  if (length(arguments) > 0) {
    txt <- paste(arguments)
    if (length(txt) == 0) return()
    strtime <- format(Sys.time(), "%I:%M:%S%p")
    txt <- paste(strtime, paste0(txt, collapse = ""))
    message(txt)
  }
}

writetext("abc", "efg") 
# 07:13:45PM abcefg
```